# AJAX request using php and js

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a program right now that registers new users and lets you log into a database without refreshing a page. So I had to use AJAX for it and externalize the php script for a better overview. Now, while I can log in, my Error handling doesnt seem to quite work. So even if I type in a wrong password, it still logs me in and just puts "wrong password" or whatever the error message is into the welcome message. I have tried adjusting the error handling with different echos, but it just doesnt work. (sorry if my explanation sucks a bit, new to this).
This is my JS code:

```
function login(username, password) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "ajaxhandler.php", true);
  xhr.onload = function() {

    if (this.responseText == "unknown user") {
      message("Login failed", "Unknown user. Please check your username and password and try again.");
    } else if (this.responseText == 'wrong password') {
      message("Login failed", "Incorrect password. Please check your username and password and try again.");
    } else if (this.responseText == "error") {
      message("Login failed", "An error occurred. Please try again later.");
    } else {
      // Login successful, update UI accordingly
      $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
      setTimeout(() => {
        message("Login success", "Welcome, " + this.responseText + "!");
        // hide login button, show button with name of user
      }, 320);
    }
  };
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('username', username);
  formData.append('password', password);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

and this is the php handling:

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('', '', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // setzt errormode auf exception --> error wird ausgegeben.
    } catch (PDOException $f) {
        echo "error";
        return;
    }
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

    try {
        $login = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM logindaten WHERE username = :usernameInput");
        $login->bindParam(':usernameInput', $username);
        $login->execute();
        $user = $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //nimmt alles von ort wo username so ist, packt in array mit column name als indikator
        if ($user) {
            $password_hash = $user['password'];
            if (password_verify($password, $password_hash)) {
                echo $username;
            } else {
                echo "wrong password";
            }
        } else {
            echo "unknown user";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $f) {
        echo "error";
    }
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

I expected it to give out an error mesage when the password was wrong, but instead, the success message was output, with the error message from php in the welcome message.Thank you for your help

Comment: Add `console.log(this.responseText)` to see what's being returned.

Comment: Instead of lots of hard-coded strings like this, I suggest you return JSON, e.g. `echo json_encode(['success' => true/false, 'message' => "Reason for the error"]);`

Comment: Well, what was throwing me off is that it does return the right message, so e.g. "wrong password", but my if doesnt seem to catch it for some reason, so it still continues to the successful login in the else. Where would I have to incorporate the code you sent?

Comment: I suspect there's something else being returned along with it, maybe extra whitespace. Try using `this.responseText.trim()`

Comment: yeah you were right. Thanks a lot man. About the code you sent- how could I use that to clean up the checks?

Comment: Then you would use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object, and use `if (response.success)` to check if it was successful or failed. Consider what happens in your version if there's a user named `error`.

Comment: Consider using a generic message for both “invalid username” and “invalid password” - https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#authentication-and-error-messages

Comment: yeah that's true, thanks. Ill try to change it all to generic messages with an error check. Thank you for your help! I just did it like this now and everything seems to work:     $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'invalid username'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);

Comment: `catch (PDOException $f) {
        echo "error";
    }`...this is an anti-pattern. It just hides the error so then you can't debug it because you don't know specifically what went wrong. Let it fail, let PHP log the error to its log file, and then the browser will just see a 500 error which you can handle and display something generic to the user on the client side instead.